# is ToInt32() an extension method in C#? specially Convert.ToInt32()

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, extension-methods

does `ToInt32()` is extension method in C#? specially `Convert.ToInt32()`

Comment: When you searched the internet for Convert.ToInt32, was the documentation you found insufficient? When you searched for what an extension method is, was something unclear? This question is poorly researched and is not the level of effort that we expect on this site.

Comment: To @AnthonyPegram's point, while the Convert class does not document any of it's members as extension methods or not, that is telling because if a method is an extension method, the authors would surely want you to know about, otherwise they wouldn't have made the method an extension method.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram after searching on  internet i put the question on this site as member over here are having different level of knowledge

Comment: @Pavan: it looks like you have several good answers below. It is customary here to accept one using the tick mark, to upvote them if appropriate, or to add comments under each if you have further questions. Would you do that now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. An extension method's raison d'être is to allow the instance method invocation syntax to be used for methods declared outside the type. You'll find that you cannot do that with any of the `Convert.ToInt32` methods.

For example, the type `String` does not have a `ToInt32(String)` member method. If you wanted to convert a `String` to an `Int32`, you could write a static method like this:

```
public static class StringConverters
{
    public static Int32 ToInt32(String number)
    {
        return Int32.Parse(
            number, 
            NumberStyles.Integer,           
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat);
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
var n = StringConverters.ToInt32("12345");
```

or, (in some cases this would be acceptable)

```
using static StringConverters; 
…
var n = ToInt32("12345");
```

But, if you want to call with the instance method invocation syntax, you would create an extension method as static method with first parameter `this` in a non-generic, non-nested, static class:

```
public static class StringConverters 
{
    public static Int32 ToInt32(this String number)
    {
        return Int32.Parse(
            number, 
            NumberStyles.Integer,           
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat);
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
var n = "12345".ToInt32();
```

The `String` type still does does not have a `ToInt32(String)` member. It just appears that the `ToInt32` declaration has extended that type. That's why it is called an extension method.

Answer (score 4):

`Convert.ToInt32()` is not an extension method, it is a static method inside the static class `Convert`.

However, you can create an extension method to do that like this:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static Int32 ToInt32(this object obj)
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(obj);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
object obj = 5;

int five = obj.ToInt32();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can press F12 on ToInt32() and you can see

```
namespace System
{
    public static class Convert
    {
        public static int ToInt32(object value);
    }
}
```

So not a extension but static

The extension in C# in something like below

```
public static int MethodName(this String str)
{
    ...
}
```